# Unable to remove item from hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

In Powershell, I have a hash table that contains data similar to this -

```
Name                   Value                                           
----                   -----                                           
1-update.bat           1                                               
2-update.bat           2                                               
3-update.bat           3                                               
3.1-update.bat         3.1                                             
4-update.bat           4
```

I also have an variable that contians a number, for example `3`

What I would like to do is loop through the array and remove any entry where the value is less than or equal to `3`

I'm thinking that this will be easy, especially as [the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) say that has tables contain a `.remove` method.  However, the code I have below fails, yeilding this error -

> Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a
>   fixed size."

Here is the code that I used -

```
$versions = @{}
$updateFiles | ForEach-Object {
    $versions.Add($_.name, [decimal]($_.name -split '-')[0])
}

[decimal]$lastUpdate = Get-Content $directory\$updatesFile

$versions | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.Value -le $lastUpdate ) {
        $versions.Remove($version.Name)
    }
}
```

I first tried to loop `$versions` in a different manner, trying both the `foreach` and `for` approaches, but both failed in the same manner.

I also tried to create a temporary array to hold the name of the versions to remove, and then looping that array to remove them, but that also failed.

Next I hit Google, and while I can find several similar questions, none that answer my specific question.  Mostly they suggest using a list (`New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]`), whcih from what I can tell is of no help to me here.

Is anyone able to suggest a fix?

Comment: Is that your actual code? Where did `$version` come from in the `$version.Name` clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go, you can use .Remove(), you just need a clone of the hashtable so that it will let you remove items as you enumerate.

```
[hashtable]$ht = @{ '1-update.bat'=1;'2-update.bat'=2;'3-update.bat'=3;'3.1-update.bat'=3.1; '4-update.bat'=4    }

#Clone so that we can remove items as we're enumerating
$ht2 = $ht.Clone()
foreach($k in $ht.GetEnumerator()){ 
    if([decimal]$k.Value -le 3){
        #notice, deleting from clone, then return clone at the end
        $ht2.Remove($k.Key) 
    } 
}


$ht2
```

Notice I've cast the original variable too so that it's explicitly a hash table, may not be required, but I like to do it to at least keep things clear.

Comment: +upvote for mentioning that you can't remove while enumerating, very important

Comment: This works, but that's a real pain having to clone the object.  It seems that something that should be very simple has been made extremely difficult by MS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just confused `ForEach-Object` with `foreach` but only halfway (maybe it was `foreach` before and you converted it).

You can't send a `[hashtable]` directly to `ForEach-Object`; the `$_` in that case will just refer to the single `[hashtable]` you sent in. You can do:

```
foreach ($version in $versions.GetEnumerator()) {
    $version.Name
    $version.Value
}
```

or you can do something like this:

```
$versions.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $_  # the name/key
    $versions[$_]  # the value
    $versions.$_   # also the value
}
```

Comment: Never seen that `GetEnumerator()` method used before, that's pretty slick. A more direct code sample for his case I think would be `$versions.Keys | ?{$versions.$_ -le $lastUpdate}|%{$Versions.Remove($_)}`

Comment: Ah agreed, that version  would make a fine answer as well

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Someone suggested almost exsacty the same as an answer, but it didn't work.  Your suggestion also fails I'm afraid, with the same "Collection was of a fixed size" error as I am already seeing. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, wrap the first part in a subexpression and it works fine: `$($versions.Keys) | ?{$versions.$_ -le $lastUpdate}|%{$Versions.Remove($_)}`. This way it outputs the entire array of keys before it tries to modify the hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ht.Keys  # list all keys
$ht[$_] # take an element of hastable
$ht.Remove($_)  # remove an element of hastable by his key
```

what you want:

```
$ht.Keys | ? { $ht[$_] -le 3 } | %{$ht.Remove($_) }
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code also provide some explanation of what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work - "Index operation failed; the 
array index evaluated to null."

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a temporary array to hold the name/key of the versions to remove, and then looping that array to remove them from hash table:

```
$versionKeysToRemove = $versions.Keys | Where-Object { $versions[$_] -le $lastUpdate }
$versionKeysToRemove | ForEach-Object { $versions.Remove($_) }
```

Or shorter:

```
($versions.Keys | ? { $versions[$_] -le $lastUpdate }) | % { $versions.Remove($_) }
```

Please note the parentheses.